# Как убрать фоновые надписи в VS

Tags: visual-studio

VS стал показывать подобные фоновые надписи:
[image: photo]

Как можно это убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется inline hints, можно убрать в настройках редактора или сочетанием Ctrl Ctrl (или Alt + F1).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Так долго мучался, а оказалось решается просто